# How to check if blockchain is downloading correctly or not?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

I've few questions:

1) How to check Eth chain is downloading or not?

2) Does chaindata folder contain the whole blockchain?

3) How to check if blockchain downloading is completed?

4) After blockchain is downloaded, How to keep it synced on server all the time?

Answer (score 0):

1 ) Any blockchain downloader client available, will show continuous logging when downloading the blockchain with block numbers and all, so you can use that to determine whether it is downloading correctly or not. the client will redownload corrupted blocks and ensure their integrity.

2) If you are trying to download the ethereum blockchain right now, you are going to download all the blockchain ( a new idea is being debated on whether that should stay or not) so yes it contains the blockchain data.

3) The blockchain download will be complete when the terminal (client ) you are using, displays the last block number that has been mined, you can check that out on many websites.

4) as long as you are running the terminal who you started downloading the blockchain with, it will keep synchronizing. you can shut it down and rerun the client again to go through the process of downloading new blocks.

Comment: im running geth --fast with supervisor utility to download blockchain automatically when my putty is closed

This is how screen shows text while downloading blockchain correctly?


INFO [02-16|13:53:06] Imported new state entries               count=1016 elapsed=1.101s    processed=1174740 pending=18143 retry=2   duplicate=508 unexpected=1011



however size of chaindata folder keeps increasing..

yes im downloading blockchain right now and this is very firs time im doing it

Answer (score 0):

Here is my ans:

> 1) How to check Eth chain is downloading or not?

Add verbosity parameter to know more information. Or if you attach geth client and run `eth.syncing`

> 2) Does chaindata folder contain the whole blockchain?

Yes,

> 3) How to check if blockchain downloading is completed?

By using eth.syncing, or compare current block with online block explore sites.

> 4) After blockchain is downloaded, How to keep it synced on server all the time?

If you running eth client, will sync blocks to local system. Lets assume peers are down then at that time it will not sync until new peer found. Again Eth will download all blocks from last sync'd blocks.

Comment: eth.syncing displays false and after few seconds it starts showing some text like this INFO [02-16|13:53:06] Imported new state entries               count=1016 elapsed=1.101s    processed=1174740 pending=18143 retry=2   duplicate=508 unexpected=1011.... Does it means its downloading blockchain right now?

Comment: however with above line displaying in the terminal size of chaindata folder keeps increasing with new .ldb files.. Does it mean everything is going OK?

Comment: Wait a few seconds and it will prompt result...

Comment: looks like i should wait for full blockchain download. it may take like 2 to 4 days as i have read on the internet... im using 1MB RAM ubuntu server just for learning

Comment: im stucked with this error....... Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: write /root/.ethereum/geth/chaindata/230944.ldb: no space left on device